# Parsing specific features from Genbank by label?

Tags: python, genbank

I'm trying to parse a Genbank file to find a specific feature. I can pull it out if I know the feature type (e.g. repeat_region). E.g. if I'm looking for this feature:

```
 repeat_region   5623..5756
                 /label=5' ITR
                 /note="5' ITR"
```

I know that I can find it using:

```
for feature in reference.features:
    if feature.type == "repeat_region":
        print(feature.location)
```

But I don't trust that it will always be a repeat_region. Instead, I'd like to look for it by label (5' ITR). I can seem to find a way to parse that from the feature object. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `/label=5'ITR` is called a **qualifier**. You can look for those qualifiers:

```
for feature in reference.features:
    for k, v in feature.qualifiers.items():
        if k == "label" and v == ["5' ITR"]:  # or "5' ITR" in v
            print(feature.location)
```